# Difference of DMA and eDMA drivers /APIs in NXP S32K144

Tags: uart, dma, nxp-microcontroller

I am using S32DS to develop a piece of software that reads data from LPUART and the tranfers the data to SRAM using DMA without any CPU intervention. The board I am using is S32K144. There are many examples given by NXP itself ,out of which I found two of them really relevant to my project.

1. **DMA_s32k144** - which uses conventions like below
   [image: example1]
2. **edma_transfer_s32k144** - while edma uses something like this
   [image: example2]

The DMA code in 1st example code seems really simple to me , while the 2nd one is a bit complicated. I am now confused which one should I be using? I am new to the whole development situation. Could someone clarify the difference between these two examples?

Also I should mention , the 2nd example is from a certain SDK and 1st one does not have any SDK ( also does not have any processor Expert generated for it). I kind of get the instinct that I should use the second one but I would like to know the difference.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for speed, the first example is probably better. Since the second one is using an SDK, chances are you are just filling in structures and calling functions that duplicate what is being done in the first example.

Comment: Thank you, that clears some confusion. Although the piece of software i am going to develop is a part of a bigger project, which is based on a SDK. Is it alright to still use the 1st example convention?